# why authentication mode="Forms" in subfolder is not supporting?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

In our  project we  have many folders.I have authenticate my folder separately,without  the help of root web.config.because  web.config is always update by x person.i need all my control to a separate folder.
When i am trying to changing the "authentication mode" to root web.config,its working .but  not in the subfolder, it is  not working in my subfolderfolder web.config.

My question is : can web.config permission is associated to particular folder?
         ,without the help of root config?if not why it is not possible?(looking for the theory)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the root web.config by putting a new web.config under your own subdirectory, or defining a [<location>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.71).aspx) element to the root web.config.